# Issue on Concatenating Two Select Options val() Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to concatenate the `val()` of two Select Option List result at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/Cn9SQ/) but I am not getting any result! I first tried :

```
var res = senselectval+kwselectval;
$("#sum").on("click",function(){
  alert(res);
});
```

which I got `NaN` in the result then I tried:

```
var res = senselectval.concat(kwselectval);
$("#sum").on("click",function(){
  alert(res);
});
```

now I got the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'concat' of undefined` can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What's your (relevant) html, and what sort of values are you working with/expecting?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4xZ2N/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put `concat` line inside the `click` event of **button**, otherwise it is executed on the page load and at that time `senselectval` is `null` so concat method throws `exception` .

Instead of:

```
var res = senselectval.concat(kwselectval);  
    $("#sum").on("click",function(){


    alert(res);
    });
```

do this:

```
 $("#sum").on("click",function(){

    var res = senselectval.concat(kwselectval);  
    alert(res);
    });
```

Here is updated script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var senselectval;
var kwselectval;
$('#senselect').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()==1){
        console.log($(this).val()+ "Cant be login")
    }
    else{
    senselectval =$(this).val();
        console.log(senselectval);
    }
});

$('#kwselect').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()==1){
        console.log($(this).val()+ "Cant be login")
    }
    else{
    kwselectval =$(this).val();
        console.log(kwselectval);
    }
});
//var res = senselectval+kwselectval;

$('#sum').click(function(){
    var res = senselectval.concat(kwselectval);
  alert(res);
});

});
```

[**HERE is Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8z3SC/)

Answer (score 2):

This line is executed when the script first runs, when both `senselectval` and `kwselectval` are undefined...

```
var res = senselectval+kwselectval;
```

Try moving the concatenation inside the click event...

```
var res;

$("#sum").on("click",function(){
    res = senselectval + kwselectval;
    alert(res);
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqW4S/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation method and put the res variable values inside the click function as @Anthony Chu:

```
//res = senselectval + kwselectval; // not here
$(document).on("click","#sum",function(){
  res = senselectval + kwselectval;
  alert(res);
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn9SQ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 var senselectval;
    var kwselectval;
```

to>

```
var senselectval="";
var kwselectval="";
```

just define both;